# YouTube Data API: video.list endpoint returning 400 error invalid filters

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am using YouTube Data Api v3 to fetch video statistics from a YouTube channel. But I am getting the error message below. I searched online, but couldn't figure out the error because I am not using the parameter in the request.

```
# Define the YouTube API request to fetch the statistics of the videos
videos_stats_request = youtube.videos().list(
    part='statistics',
    id=','.join(video_ids),
    maxResults=50
)
```

Error message:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos returned "The request specifies an invalid filter parameter.". Details: "[{'message': 'The request specifies an invalid filter parameter.', 'domain': 'youtube.parameter', 'reason': 'invalidFilters', 'location': 'parameters.', 'locationType': 'other'}]">
```

Comment: It seems like you're using this in accordance with [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets). I don't see anything about there being a limit to the number of `id`s, but maybe you could try it with fewer video IDs? How many do you have there currently?

Comment: Thanks, you're right, the problem is the ids limit. Looks like the request can process max 50 ids.

Comment: You're correct [@Karthik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197937/karthik), cf [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint [`maxResults`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#maxResults).